# How to declare a component in NgModule, when the component includes sub components ?

Tags: angular

In angular. How do you declare a component in a NgModule, when the components includes sub components ?

An example of this

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './components/navbar/navbar.component';
import { TrackComponent } from './components/track/track.component';

@NgModule({
imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
declarations: [ AppComponent, NavbarComponent, TrackComponent],
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

TrackComponent contains 3 sub components:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {SkillComponent} from './skill-level/skilllevel.component';
import {TrackheaderComponent} from './header/trackheader.component';

@Component({
moduleId: module.id,
selector: 'trackelement',
templateUrl: 'track.component.html'
})

export class TrackComponent {
private title: string;

constructor() {
    this.title = 'title';
  }
}
```

I am using angular-cli (ng serve to test locally), but the console (and my IDE) are saying that TrackComponent hasn't been declared in any NgModule.

I've tried a couple of things:

1. Declaring all sub components in app.module.ts.
2. Creating a new NgModule in TrackComponent.ts which exported the components.

So my question is more precise this: 
What is the RIGHT way to do this? - the right way to have a 'tree' of components. 
I'm trying to follow good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to import the components like this

```
import {SkillComponent} from './skill-level/skilllevel.component';
import {TrackheaderComponent} from './header/trackheader.component';
```

Unless, you're actually using those classes in some other way.

If you're under the assumption that the fact that `TrackComponent` uses those component , thus you need to import them in `TrackComponent`, you're wrong .

That aside, you normally declare the components in the root app module , unless you specifically want them to be separated as a whole entity as a module, in that case you'd need to create another module, declare and export those components in that module and import the that module in your root module.

Comment: Well.. how then?

Comment: Why would you do that to begin with /